# Debugging by attaching a process for windows phone apps

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I'm currently running VS2013 Update 3, I'm building an app and i;m trying to mimic the Rate My App that shows up rate message dialog in b/w specified intervals.

My problem is that i've made a setting using ApplicationData.current.loclasettings and it is an integer.

and i want to see the settings number being updated every time i close and run the app to ensure the logic is perfect.

but i'm unable to do it. Every time i deploy the app from vs it replace the original app and thus erasing all the settings that have been previously saved.

I've tried to use attach a process but it doesnt work on windowsphones.

Comment: VS should only replace the data if you do a "Rebuild" step. If you just "Build" then it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: it's not about building the solution . the app is on my phone not an emulator ..

Comment: How do you deploy it to your phone? Why not just use F5 to debug on launch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after a bit of research and going through the documentation it is clear that there is no way you can attach a process to the app  that is already running on the phone.

At least for me there was no other way because Microsoft kept the USB debugging thing a little bit undocumented or not documented at all.

So, who ever are looking forward to first launch the app on a connected windows phone and then start the the connect to a process and select the appropriate device for communication , story it is not possible, at least the build that i;m using doesn't support. may there might be a better solution in the future.